# indentation problem with gulp autoprefixer?

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, indentation, autoprefixer

I know this is low priority, but i have noticed that gulp autoprefixer has ruined my css code indentation to a style like this:

```
-webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em;
```

I do not know if i should fix this manually or just this style is acceptable and i can leave it alone???

Comment: You can "leave it" like that, but if you are use Gulp and keep your source files, why not minify your css, then the indentation wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [gulp-postcss](https://github.com/postcss/gulp-postcss) with npm package autoprefixer. ([example](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#gulp))

With postcss you are a lot more flexible. There are many [postcss-plugins](https://www.postcss.parts/) which helps to get the optimal CSS.

To get the right formatting with correct indentation you can run the [postcss-prettify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-prettify) plugin after the autoprefixer.

If you later need a minified CSS for production use, you can use [cssnano](https://cssnano.co/).

Answer (score 1):

I would also look at the cascade option to autoprefixer.  It looks like it might be the source of your bad indentation.  Try:

```
autoprefixer({ cascade: false })
```

The default value is `true` and may be giving you the results you are seeing.

[autoprefixer options](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#options)